# How can I learn the starting time of each frame in a video?

Tags: image, matlab, video, frame

It is very critical to learn the start time of each frame of a video.
I need to determine the starting point manually ( for example 848 here) by using below matlab code:

```
v = VideoReader('video1.avi','CurrentTime',848);
while hasFrame(v)
    video_frame = readFrame(v);
    counter=counter+1;

    if counter==1
        imshow(video_frame)
        imhist(video_frame(:,:,1))
    end
end
```

What I want is to distinguish some video frame from the others by using histogram. At the end my aim is to reach the exact showing time of the **distinguished frames**.

**After editting:**
This is frame histogram outputs: 
[image]

Histogram size of the some frames are different from the previous one, do you know the reason?

```
     difference=[difference sum(abs(histcounts(video_frame)-histcounts(lastframe)))];
```

Because of the taking the difference of the I had remove the different histogram sized frames but it causes missing some frames.

Comment: just to clear things up: you have a video that shows something (e.g. a black screen) for some time, then a cut happens that can be found using histograms and you want that to be found automaticallly, right? Can you give an example video file? that would be super helpful

Comment: Yes exactly.                                                                              Unfortunately I can not share the video because of some copyright problems. Video consists of in the first scene a man face and background is black, in the second scene there are some text and backround is dark white, and finaly third scene is blank and background is again dark white.  Could you answer it for a random video please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i havent found an video example that looks like what you discribe. please condsider always to have an example.

This example code calculates the differences in the histcounts. please notice that `waitforbuttonpress`is in the loop so you have to click for each frame while testing or remove it when the video is too long. Does this works on your file?

```
v = VideoReader('sample.avi','CurrentTime',1);
figure1=figure('unit','normalized','Position',[0.2 0.2 0.4 0.6]);
axes1=subplot(3,1,1);
axes2=subplot(3,1,2);
axes3 = subplot(3,1,3);

counter=0;
difference=[];
video_frame=readFrame(v);
while hasFrame(v)
    lastframe=video_frame;
    video_frame = readFrame(v);
    counter=counter+1;

    imshow(video_frame,'Parent',axes1);
    [a,b]=histcounts(video_frame(:,:,1));
    plot(b(1:end-1),a,'Parent',axes2);

    difference=[difference sum(abs(histcounts(video_frame,0:255)-histcounts(lastframe,0:255)))];
    bar(1:counter,difference,'Parent',axes3);
    waitforbuttonpress
end
  [~,onedistinguished]=max(difference);
  %defining a threshold like every value that is bigger 4000
   multidistinguished=find(difference>4000);

  disp(['majorly changed at: ' num2str(distinguished)]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Finn, it works. But how can I determine the exact time of the each frame? And it should be more than one pick points on the histogram, I mean more than one distinguished frames and their showing times.

Comment: regarding the time (i assume you mean in seconds): if you know the framerate of your video you can simply calculate it by framenumber/framerate. but i am not sure if the infromation about the framerate is stored inside the file. multiple distinguised is easy but you would have to show the bar plot of the differences. Those are not copyright protected

Comment: I have answered in the main question. Thanks Finn.

Comment: The histograms size depends on the range of values. RGB has values in [0,255] but if a picture just has values in the range [0,200] the histogramm will only be that size too. i edited my answer code, so the issue should be fixed. regarding you multiple distinguised frames: i dont know where the right ones are but you could go for a threshold for example. i added that in the end of my code as well